# Telegram message will go to my personal chat id but not to a group id or id of another user

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to send messages to a group or a user that's not me using the following code

```
import requests
token = "my_bot_token"
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}"

Index = "Hola"
myPersonalId = "my_personal_id"
params = {"chat_id": myPersonalId, "text": Index} #John
r = requests.get(url + "/sendMessage", params=params)

JosephId = "Joseph_ID"
params = {"chat_id": JosephId, "text": Index} #Joseph
r = requests.get(url + "/sendMessage", params=params)
```

The first one works but the second one doesn't work. Other answers which I have seen make it sound pretty straight forward. As long as you have the id there should be no problem. P.S. Code is executed without any error.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I know, `requests.get` doesn't necessarily throw an exception if the request wasn't successful. You should inspect the result (`r`) to check the status code and see if the request was successful.
2. Bots can't initiate conversations with users, so `Joseph` will need to send a message to the bot before the bot can send a message to Joseph.